# System Restore mismatch

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

My wife's laptop (Windows 10 Pro x64) won't boot up.  We've tried the repair options and they didn't work.  I created a System Restore disk on my work (Windows 10 Enterprise x64) machine.  I booted my wife's laptop with the System Restore disk and tried various repair options with no success.  I was able to get to a DOS prompt and view the files on the hard drive, so the hard drive is somewhat functional.  I'm wondering if the reason the System Restore disk repairs didn't work because there's a mismatch between the PC the restore disk was generated on and the one that I'm trying to use it on.  Should I recreate the Restore Disk on my personal Windows 10 Pro laptop?

Comment: “I'm wondering if the reason the System Restore disk repairs didn't work because there's a mismatch between the PC the restore disk was generated on and the one that I'm trying to use it on.” - Unlikely, however, you didn’t provide specifics on why it failed.  You should edit your question to include the necessary information to answer your question

Comment: The current WinRE is pretty much identical between different versions of Windows 10 (and editions), only the newest Insider Preview builds, would be significantly different.

Comment: Have you downloaded the Windows 10 Pro x64 ISO with the MS Media Creation Tool, and tried using that for repair (without deleting user files)?